# Position UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

Good evening,

I would like to position my custom tableview cell the same as the next picture: [image]

Currently i've got this:
[image]

How can i add a margin on the tableviewcell? I've already tried to different things with separatorInsets and contentInsets, but i can't get the desired result.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you implemented heightForRowAtIndexPath(iOS 7+) or estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath(iOS 8) to define the height for cells?

Comment: Or is this a static table?

Comment: I defined a static height of 60 in the storyboard. Can i better implement the estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: yes, try to implement it.

Comment: It doesn't actually change the height of the cell..

Comment: you need to set tableview delegate. estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath needs support from constraints, while heightForRowAtIndexPath can define a height in your case.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put all your content inside a `UIView`, instead of directly adding them to the `contentView`. Then you add some margin from this `view`to the `contentView` (from your screenshot, should be left, right, top and bottom).

An easy way to embed all your view in a parent view, would be the following: Select all your subviews and go to `Editor -> Embed In -> View`

[image]

Make sure you set the background color for the contentView of the cell to `clearColor`.

This is how the storyboard should look like (you have more than just one label, of course)

[image]

There is no other way, using `tableViews` to have the cells smaller, in width, than the entire tableView.

Another option would be to use a `collectionView` instead. There you can specify both width and height for your cells, so obtaining that layout would be easier.

Let me know if you need more help :)

---

> Implementing custom selection to take the padding into account

For this you will need the following:

You will need to add a `UIImageView` as subview as your view that has the padding, like this:

[image: ImageView in storyboard]

As you can see from the screenshot, you will need to set the `image` and the `highlightedImage` for the `UIImageView`. The image will be a simple white image, and the `highlightedImage` and image with the background color you want. For me my too pictures looked like this:

[image]
[image]

Then, in your custom `UITableViewCell` class you do the following:

```
@interface MyTableViewCell()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *highlightImageView;

@end

@implementation MyTableViewCell

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.highlightImageView setHighlighted:selected]; 
}

-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // this will change the color on your image
    [self.highlightImageView setHighlighted:highlighted];
}
```

> Swift implementation

```
@IBOutlet weak var highlightedView: UIImageView!

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    highlightedView.highlighted = selected
}

override func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    highlightedView.highlighted = highlighted

}
```

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks Catalina, this fixed it! It also looks like an clean solution :) I'm quite a newbie in iOs development, but you can change many things in the xcode editor but also in the code. What is for instance the preferred way to set background colors, font-sizes and other similar settings?

Comment: That's great, you're welcome! About the theming, it depends on your project. For example, if the colors and fonts are not that likely to change, you can do it in the storyboard. But if you have a bigger project, many viewControllers in the storyboard, I would suggest to do it in code, since setting everything right in the storyboard can be quite tedious. Maybe using a category on UI elements (like `UILabel`, `UIView`, etc) with something like `applyDefaultTheme`, where you do your stuff. This would be easy to call from code and would guarantee you have a consistent interface.

Comment: Cool, i didn't know you can apply themes to your project, thanks! The only problem i have now, is that the hover state of the table cell overlays the full width of the cell, so the margins are ignored in the hover state. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Should I update my answer with a solution to this or you wanna write another question?

Comment: Hi Catalina, sorry for my late answer.. I've had a busy week at work. I've followed all your steps and the highlighted image works! But the default grey highlight is still visible. I think there's something wrong with the code.
I use this code and do super.setHighlighted, because self.highlightedView.setHighlighted doesn't work.

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setHighlighted(selected, animated: animated)
    }

Comment: I have tested the code, so it should work. If you still see the default highlight, that is because you are still calling super. This is the reason, the code I posted does not call the super. What do you mean `self.highlightedView.setHighlighted` does not work? What's wrong exactly?

Comment: I added the error in the gist description: https://gist.github.com/MathijsK93/cb653718087b7452f47d

Comment: I have updated my answer with the corresponding swift implementation. you were just calling the method wrong in swift.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use nested views:

View 1: Add a view to the content view of the cell which is pinned to the edges a 0 points. Make the background color grey. or make it transparent and set the table background to grey.

View 2: inside view 1

Pin this to the edges of view 1 with leading and trailing margins to match your grey border. Use top and bottom pins with size equal to half the grey margin between cells.

Make the background colour of this view the color of the left thin vertical color bar on your picture.

CTRL drag this view to create an IBOutlet in your code so you can change the color in the cell on a per cell basis.

View 3: inside view 2.

Make this white and pin it at 0 points on top, bottom and trailing edge to view 2.

Pin the leading edge to the thickness of the coloured vertical bar.

Finally put your text etc in view 3 and lay it out.

This will give you the layout you wish.